Unable to access tomcat webapp running on Kubernetes Pod with load balancer
I have the following deployment yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rest-deployment
  labels:
    app: rest-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rest-deployment
  replicas: 1 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rest-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rest-deployment
          image: public.ecr.aws/apryse/fluent-restful:24.2.1.4
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: restful-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: rest-deployment
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer


My goal is to have multiple pods running in this cluster, all managed by the load balancer, but I wanted to get it working with one pod first.
My issue is I cannot access the tomcat webapp after i launch the deployment.
I can see that my pod is running when i run kubectl get deployments
I can see that the  loadBalancer is running when i run kubectl describe svc restful-service. If it helps this is what that returns:
Name:                     restful-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=rest-deployment
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       obfuscatedIP_1
IPs:                      obfuscatedIP_1
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30416/TCP
Endpoints:                obfuscatedIP_2:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>

Tomcat on the container is configured to listen on port 8080:
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />

But I cannot seem to access the webapp, ive tried:

localhost:8080
obfuscatedIP_1:8080
obfuscatedIP_2:8080

None of these work. Based on what ive seen in documentation and online this setup should work so any insight as to why it doesnt would be much appreciated!

What sort of Kubernetes environment are you using?  Is there anything that would have provisioned an actual load balancer?

@DavidMaze just on docker desktop. To my knowledge nothing is provisioning a load balancer other than my deployment yaml

@DavidMaze doing more research I can see that Kubernetes does not directly offer a load balancing component. Ultimately I want to be able to access my webapp on localhost. I tried doing NodePort but it didnt work for me.. any suggestions?

If your goal is a single-host developer-oriented setup, Kubernetes probably isn't the right environment.  It's usually a remote clustered environment, and services won't usually be running on the same system as the end user's browser.

Got it working with the following service instead of a loadbalancer:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rest-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: rest-deployment
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      # By default and for convenience, the `targetPort` is set to
      # the same value as the `port` field.
      targetPort: 8080
      # Optional field
      # By default and for convenience, the Kubernetes control plane
      # will allocate a port from a range (default: 30000-32767)
      nodePort: 30007

